# Why is my code printing out more print statements then it should?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, terminal

Heyo all. I just got a raspberry pi 4 and I moved my code from my PC to the pi and when I ran and fixed it so it could run. I started to notice that it printed out more then it should. I looked it up but I couldn't find any help or reason why it does it. Code is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from os import system
system('cls')
print('heyo')
```

output is

[image: OUTPUT1]

I have found out if I add a sleep timer I no longer get that problem.

[image: OUTPUT2]

I found out what caused it that is why I did not have code from my main program but I never found out exactly why it does it nor how to fix it without sleeping.

Notes: originally wrote it on windows 10 on my main PC I ported it over to my PI on the raspberry PI OS lite (I assume it is a Linux base OS). I changed the "clear" command to "cls" cause I am used to it. I am using VS code via SSH to the file. I am also using SSH to start the program. I run the code as:

```
./main.py
```

I did chmod +x test.py   I am using python version 3.6.7. I am sorry if this seems basic or I made it way to confusing or there is a super super simple way to fix it (besides time.sleep). Thank you all for any help/input. Have a good night or good day.

Edit: I did not change anything but now it works for some reason. I have no clue why or how but for some reason it does.

Comment: Is your file named `main.py` or `test.py`?  Your post mentions both names.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad typo. I made ```test.py``` as a test file to see what was causing the problem. the ```main.py``` was well the main file I used and the first file I noticed that error on. The code you see at the very top was in the ```test.py``` file. I run them both exactly the same. Hope that helps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I did not change anything but now it works for some reason. I have no clue why or how but for some reason it does." Then there is not a reproducible problem, and thus not a suitable question for the site. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Before asking a question, please try to make sure that you have identified a specific, reproducible problem; figure out a [mre] for that problem and make sure that someone else could follow simple steps with simple code and directly see the exact problem.